# How can I get content of all scripts in HTML

Tags: java, html-parsing, script-tag

I am making a Java program, which involves extraction of  tags from a webpage.For parsing, i am using Jsoup, which is working fine.But there is some problem with number of  tags in the downloaded page.
I have 4 files:-

1. goog1.htm (which i saved from https://www.google.co.in through browser )
2. goog2.html (which i downloaded using the command ' wget https://www.google.co.in ')
3. goog3.html (which i downloaded through my Java Program using BufferedReader & InputStreamReader)
4. goog4.html (which i get by copying whole code from ' view-source:https://www.google.co.in/ ' )

When i searched for the string "< script/>" in these 4 files, all gave different results.

- goog1.htm - 16 times
- goog2.html - 5 times
- goog3.html - 5 times
- goog4.html - 10 times

What's the reason for this difference ? How to get all script tags from a page ?

Which file should i use for testing my program ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *"Which file should i use for testing my program ?"*  Perhaps one from a web service that does not go to extremes to **prevent** programmatic access (like Google does)?

Comment: Did you handle taking the content from those sites or you asking for it too ?

Answer (score 1):

1) The reason of different number of `script` tags is there can be multiple `script` tags defined in a `HTML` page.

2) All script tags in a page are loaded and they will be running. If you wanna test all script codes, you need to test with all of them. It depends on your testing scope.

3) If you handled taking the content as text into your JAVA program you can get all script tags content by parsing with substring methods. But I recommend using `Apache commons StringUtils` class to do this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class scriptContentRetriever{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yourScriptContent = "<script>This is Script 1 Content</script><script>This is Script 2 Content</script>";
        String[] scriptStrings = StringUtils.substringsBetween(yourScriptContent, "<script>", "</script>");
        for (String scriptString : scriptStrings) {
            //Do what ever you want with the script content right here.
            System.out.println(scriptString);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But the problem is in HTML pagecontent. My code  to get page content is String pageContent = Jsoup.connect("www.google.co.in").get(); which should contain 10 <script> tags, but it contain only 5.